# Troubleshooting git pull

Tags: git, ubuntu, tortoisegit, git-pull

I've set up a git repo via ssh on an Ubuntu box I'm using as a media center/backup server.

the steps I took were:

```
cd repos
git init <repoName>
cd <repoName>
git config --bool core.bare true
```

I've been able to successfully push and pull from my desktop and laptop via TortoiseGit, however a git pull via SSH returns:

```
fatal: /usr/lib/git-core/gitpull cannot be used without a working tree.
```

I'm very new to terminal/ssh so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: By the way, you can do `git init --bare myrepo` to save a step there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to push to a bare repo. Pull will not work as it requires a working directory to merge to, which is what the error message that you see says.

So setup a remote to the bare repo from the repo that you will be working on and push from that.

PS: The ideal way to create a bare repo is to do `git init --bare <reponame>`

Comment: thank you for the answers. I think I need to look into the differences between a regular repo and a bare repo to see why I'm using bare in the first place...

Comment: now i remember why:

! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://

Comment: @Bms85smb - Yeah, it is standard practice to have the repo that you push to a bare one.

Comment: Forgive me but now i'm confused... Shouldn't I have to push & pull? i.e I create a repo via ssh < clone it on my laptop & pc < make changes (laptop) < commit master (laptop) < push (laptop) < Pull pc & SSH (Ubuntu)

Comment: @Bms85smb - You have a bare repo as central repo and only push TO that or pull FROM that. But you NEVER PULL IN that.

Comment: So i probably want a regular repo? The only problem is I get the error shown above and can't push...

Comment: @Bms85smb - Any repo that you push to has to be a bare repo. You need a bare repo. You just push to it but not pull in it.

Comment: Thanks for the help manojlds, I got it figured out. A bare repo is a "non working repo" that is why I can't pull into it. If I wanted to work from my Ubuntu box id have to clone the repo elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

A bare repository doesn't have a working tree. `git pull` is functionally the same as a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`, and to do a merge you have to have a working tree (in case there are conflicts you need to sort out).

Comment: thanks< i don't think I want to use a bare repo then. I only used it because I read it as a solution to a push problem I was receiving (see my comment to manojlds).