# Git-Windows-git-pull cannot be used without a working tree

Tags: windows, git, github

I am facing a problem related to  Git on Windows, am unable to pull the changes from the repo on git. Am able to add, commit and push my changes, but not pull.

Its giving me an error:
fatal: C:****\Git/libexec/git-core/git-pull cannot be used without a
working tree.**

Upon searching this error i got some links on SO, which asked for removing working tree or working directory environment variables. This links seemed to be more of explaining how git works rather quoting how to solve it and none seemed specific to windows. So am posting this question

Mine is not a bare repository, here is the git config file content:

```
 [core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://username@github.com/Project/projectname.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Am using git for first time on windows am using mysgit for it. Do i need to setup other parameters or some environment variables specific to windows, as am using git on ubuntu as well with no special steps.

Also referred this link but doest seems latest as none of things specified in this post exist. [Link](http://ryanalberts.com/402/fatal-cprogram-filesgitlibexecgit-coregit-pull-cannot-be-used-without-a-working-tree/)

Any Advice or help is appreciated.

Thanks, let me know if this question is apt in this forum or Should i post it to SuperUser.

**Edit:**

After Eckes post, it helped me find out the error for missing working tree.

The workstation i am working on had one more version of git installed and when i checked for environment variables it was set to it, once i cleaned it, am not getting the previous error any more, but pull is still not working, getting an error:

---

**EDIT**

```
 remote: Counting objects: 132, done.
 remote: Compressing objects: 100% (64/64), done.
 remote: Total 104 (delta 74), reused 70 (delta 40)
 Receiving objects: 100% (104/104), 33.05 KiB, done.
 Resolving deltas: 100% (74/74), completed with 24 local objects.
 fatal: write failure on 'stdout': Bad file descriptor
 error: https://github.com/Project/projectname.git did not send all necessary objects
```

Comment: you need a worktree for pull. Did you checkout that branch?

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ Can u be more elaborate please? What do you mean by checkout that branch?
I did git clone https://github.com/Project/projectname.git -b master. I dont think i need to anything additional for pull.

Comment: do a `git status`, `git fetch` and `git pull` and post their full output.

Comment: git status proper as expected, git pull output i have posted above.

Comment: what is "proper as expected"?

Comment: i get proper status saying which files i have modified and which branch am on...which is as expected.

Comment: yes branch master, now am able to do git pull but with error please check my update with error trace.

Comment: Note: git 2.7 will fix a bug which would also trigger the same error message. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33164826/6309)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's strange. Looking at `Git/libexec/git-core/git-pull` (as of `git version 1.7.11.msysgit.0`), there's the command

```sh
require_work_tree_exists
```

The command is implemented in `Git/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup`:

```sh
require_work_tree_exists () {
  if test "z$(git rev-parse --is-bare-repository)" != zfalse
  then
    die "fatal: $0 cannot be used without a working tree."
  fi
}
```

So, if you're **really not** in a bare repo (i.e. your posted `.git/config` is really the one of your repo), this will not print out the message.

But there's another command in `Git/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup` printing out that string:

```sh
require_work_tree () {
  test "$(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null)" = true ||
  die "fatal: $0 cannot be used without a working tree."
}
```

I'd recommend changing **one** of the two messages to be able to identify which one is really relevant for you. The second one is issued if you're issuing `git` commands on directories that are no git repo directories. Just to be sure: `git pull` must be run inside a git repo...

---

**Edit:**
in order to check, what's going wrong, try the code of `require_work_tree_exists` on your git bash. It should not enter the `then` part of the code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time and replying, i changed both the messages but isn't printing my custom message for any of the methods you mentioned above. Am inside a Git Repo. +1.

Comment: @abhi: well, then they don't get executed. things getting even stranger... try to `grep` for the message in your git installation folder. Must be written somewhere...

Comment: hey thanks, that thing helped... workstation am working on had one more version of git installed and when i checked for environment variables it was set to it, once i cleaned it, am not getting the previous error any more, but pull is still not working, getting an error: 

fatal: write failure on 'stdout': Bad file descriptor
error: https://github.com/Project/projectname.git did not send all necessary objects

Any idea, why?

Comment: @abhi: no clue. try uninstalling all versions of msysgit and install only the latest one.

Comment: no luck yet, but am to pull am getting the changesets, but the changes are not merged, saying bad file descriptor 'stdout'. I thought the folder am using didnt had permissions i moved it to another drive where i had complete privileges still wasnt working, i would fix it once am back to windows. I would post a update if solved, to me it seems a machine problem, rather than Git.Thanks ur answer helped i would mark it. It can help as a guideline for others.

Answer (score 1):

See here： [Troubleshooting git pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565828/troubleshooting-git-pull)

A bare repository doesn't have a working tree. git pull is functionally the same as a git fetchfollowed by a git merge, and to do a merge you have to have a working tree (in case there are conflicts you need to sort out).

You have to push to a bare repo. Pull will not work as it requires a working directory to merge to, which is what the error message that you see says.
So setup a remote to the bare repo from the repo that you will be working on and push from that.
PS: The ideal way to create a bare repo is to do git init --bare

Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

This error ("`cannot be used without a working tree.`") can be seen on Windows when the *case* of the path in `GIT_WORK_TREE` is incorrect.
That **will be fixed with git 2.7 (Q4 2015)**

See [commit 63ec5e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63ec5e1fecc14b0dd5452f0a2b80641600b03437) (28 Sep 2015) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6652939](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6652939ce8cacb147bce2f0c3503486915ca5a73), 15 Oct 2015)</sup>

> On a case insensitive filesystems, setting `GIT_WORK_TREE` variable
>   using a random cases that does not agree with what the filesystem
>   thinks confused Git that it wasn't inside the working tree.

More precisely:

> #### `setup`: fix "inside work tree" detection on case-insensitive filesystems
>
> Git has a config variable to indicate that it is operating on a file system that is case-insensitive: `core.ignoreCase`.
>   But the `dir_inside_of()` function did not respect that.
>   As a result, if Git's idea of the current working directory disagreed in its upper/lower case with the `GIT_WORK_TREE` variable (e.g. `C:\test` vs `c:\test`) the user would be greeted by the error message:

```
fatal: git-am cannot be used without a working tree.
```

> when trying to run a rebase.
>
> This fixes [git-for-windows#402](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/402) (reported by [Daniel Harding [living180]](https://github.com/living180)).