# 'git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree' doesn't recognize working tree or subdirectories

Tags: windows, git, upgrade

After updating to the latest Windows Git (2.5.0 from 1.6.2) I find I'm unable to rebase a branch:

```
C:\core\guidewire\Dev\2.4>git checkout fhcf-assumptiondate && git rebase master
Previous HEAD position was d032e17... Merge branch 'de8041'
Switched to branch 'fhcf-assumptiondate'
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
fatal: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-am cannot be used without a working tree.
```

Comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292057/git-windows-git-pull-cannot-be-used-without-a-working-tree) hint at a Git installation conflict, but the old version is entirely removed by now, including a lingering DLL and checking for stale environment vars.

Looking inside the git scripts, I find that the error message is coming from a test in git-sh-setup that uses `git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree`. Consulting `rev-parse` directly shows that it seems to not understand that I really am inside the working copy:

```
C:\core\guidewire\Dev\2.4>dir .git
 Volume in drive C is System (Local)
 Volume Serial Number is D4EC-4ED4

 Directory of C:\core\guidewire\Dev\2.4

08/04/2015  21:16                27 .git
               1 File(s)             27 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  155,451,965,440 bytes free

C:\core\guidewire\Dev\2.4>git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
false
```

...Except some commands *are* able to correctly tell the difference:

```
C:\core\guidewire\Dev\2.4>git status
HEAD detached from refs/heads/fhcf-assumptiondate
nothing to commit, working directory clean

C:\core\guidewire\Dev\2.4>cd ..

C:\core\guidewire\Dev>git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

### What is making Git confused about whether I'm in the right directory or not?

Possible points of interest:

- Repo was created by the previous installation.
- 1.6.2 was an msys build of Git. 2.5.0 is MinGW.
- The repo was cloned with `--separate-git-dir`.
- `checkout`, `status`, `add`, `commit` and possibly others all have worked without issue since the upgrade.
- A clone of the broken repository exhibits correct behavior; 'in' or 'out' of the working tree are detected correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue using an existing (1.6.x-created) repository after upgrading to Windows Git 2.5, update the repo's gitconfig:

```
[core]
    worktree = c:/core/guidewire/Dev/2.4
```

to

```
[core]
    worktree = C:/core/guidewire/Dev/2.4
```

---

The new Git installation either obtains paths differently from the old, or is no longer case-insensitive about paths. Therefore the existing repo working tree location becomes wrong since no folder under `c:\core\guidewire\Dev\2.4` will have a prefix of `C:\core\guidewire\Dev\2.4`. [Git source for the current version](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aecce6d0eff68a7144e32247d2e02d9974772ab1/dir.c#L2038-L2063) shows no sign of case-insensitivity, so the msys fork may have modified the path-checking function, or case-smashed all paths prior to comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are in a git repo AS a configured user.
You can check your git configuration with: `git config --list`

I'm using WSL, and I have git set up for my personal user, but I do NOT have git set up for sudo.
So, I can NOT switch user to root (`sudo su -`) and then use certain commands that leverage git (such as `docker build ...`).
But, I CAN execute that same command by elevating my own permissions for a single command (example: `sudo docker build ...`).